# Getting "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" in my Chrome extension's popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

My manifest looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "This extension is a starting point to create a real Chrome extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "./public/index.html",
    "default_title": "Open the popup"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
  ]
}
```

Here is my file structure:

[image]

All I have so far is a basic react app with a manifest wired up to work as a chrome extension. What's causing my popup to not load the default react page? I've tried every variation of the index.html file location I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using create-react-app. You'll need to run `npm run build` in your base directory to compile your source files and then use the compiled files produced inside of the `build/` folder.

Comment: When i try to unpack only the build folder, it says it's missing the manifest. Do I have to move the manifest into the build folder?

Comment: Now the pop up is simply loading blank. Is there anything missing from the build file structure?: https://i.imgur.com/UAr9BZl.png

Comment: @AndrewG. That might be a problem with your code rather than your build structure